# React Native build release apk have issue " Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 "

Tags: android, react-native

My project use react native. When I build release apk my app on Android Studio 3.5.2, I sometime have an issue:

```
Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

[image]

and here version react-native and node

System:

```
OS: macOS 10.15.2
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5557U CPU @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 1.91 GB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
```

Binaries:

```
Node: 12.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
```

SDKs:

```
iOS SDK:
  Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
```

IDEs:

```
Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

npmPackages:

```
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

npmGlobalPackages:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

i don't know why? Please Help me!!! thanks you.

Comment: npx is part of npm now, there is probably a command that react native runs that is failing but that is not the error. Run the command in a terminal or command prompt and look for a error message there.

Answer (score 0):

[error's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJChp.png)

In my case, it happened after installing `react-native-gifted-chat`, so [link](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1423#issuecomment-571949741) to the instructions:

- go to node_modules/react-native-parsed-text/babel.config.js
- coomment second line // api.cache(true);
- close Metro Bundler run `yarn run ios`,
- you may need to run it twice // "ios": "react-native run-ios"